# Given two subfields, is one a subset of the other?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field. If $A$ and $B$ are subfields of $F$, is it true that $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$?

Motivation: I am wondering if we can define an order on the set of all subfields of $F$.

Comment: The reals and the algebraic closure of the rationals are both subfields of the complex numbers and neither is contained in the other.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ are both subfields of $\mathbb{R}$, but neither is included in the other.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Can you please elaborate or give a reference?

Comment: @cos_dm_math21 Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{x}):=\{a+b\sqrt{x}|a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ for $x=2,3$?

Comment: @Filippo: Yes, for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt x)$ clarification.

Comment: You can define an order on the set of all subfields, you defined it: $A\leqslant B$ if $A\subseteq B$. The problem is, as shown on the comments above, that you won't get a totally ordered set, but just a partially ordered one (like in most cases when you consider subspaces ordered by inclusion, let it be open subsets, subgroups, subfields, subrings, etc)

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you for the additional information!